# Preserving mail merge fields when editing text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing a macro to clean a table in Word. It iterates over the table and if a given cell contains a mail merge field, it should delete the rest of the text in the cell and leave the mail merge field as is. I believe my current solution doesn't work because it's writing the placeholder tag as text rather than preserving the object that is the placeholder - the text looks right, but the MM doesn't do anything. Also, this is on OSX, so I don't have access to some libraries, hence no regular expressions. How should I find and preserve the merge field object?

```
Public Sub TableSweep()

Dim oRow As row
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim cellText As String
Dim startInd As Integer
Dim endInd As Integer

'ensure cursor is within table
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    MsgBox "Can only run this within a table."
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each oRow In Selection.Tables(1).Rows

    For Each oCell In oRow.Cells

        cellText = oCell.Range
        startInd = InStr(cellText, "«")
        endInd = InStr(cellText, "»")
        If startInd > 0 And endInd > 0 And endInd > startInd Then
            cellText = (Mid(cellText, startInd, endInd - startInd + 1))
            oCell.Range = cellText
        End If

    Next oCell

Next oRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you use the `Text` property of the `Range` object to get and set the text and use the `Fields` property (`oCell.Range.Fields.Count > 0`) to see if fields exist in the cell?